# How to sign code built using Azure Pipelines using a certificate/key in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

We're in the process of moving from on-premise build servers to Azure Pipelines. We produce "shrink-wrap" desktop software so clearly we need to sign all our binaries before releasing. Our current build infrastructure does this using a USB hardware token from GlobalSign, but clearly that isn't going to work when we're doing cloud builds - sadly, clouds are not equipped with USB ports :D

Now, GlobalSign has recently started [advertising](https://www.globalsign.com/en/code-signing-certificate/) Azure Key Vault as a key storage option, and they're perfectly happy to sell this to us, but I'm not sure how we'd actually integrate that with our build pipelines (or indeed whether that's even possible).

Has anyone actually made this work?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## Code Signing

I've been battling with Azure Key Vault and Azure Pipelines to get our code signed, and succeeded. So here's what I found out.

Critically, Extended Validation (EV) certificates used for code signing are very different animals to 'normal' SSL certificates. The standard ones can be exported as much as you like, which means you can upload it to Azure Pipelines and use it with the standard Microsoft Sign Tool.

However, once an EV certificate is in Azure Key Vault, it isn't coming out in any usual fashion. You must call it from Pipelines using the excellent [Azure Sign Tool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool) as discovered by [Anodyne above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57490154/5363308)

Get your certificate into Key Vault. You can use any certificate authority you like to generate the certificate, as long as they understand that you'll need an EV certificate, and critically one that has a **hardware security module (HSM)**, and **not** one with a physical USB key. Any cloud based system like Key Vault will need an HSM version.

To get the permissions to access this certificate externally you can [follow this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) but **beware** it misses a step. So read that document first, then these summarised steps, to get the Key Vault set up:

1. Open the Azure portal, go to the `Azure Active Directory` area, and create an `App registration`: put in a memorable name, ignore the `Redirect URI`, and save it.
2. Go to your specific `Key Vault`, then `Access control (IAM)`, then `Add role assignment`. Type the name of the app you just created into the `select` input box. Also choose a `Role`, I suggest `Reader` and then save.
3. **The Missing Part:** Still in the Key Vault, click the `Access policies` menu item. Click `Add Access Policy` and add your application. The `Certificate Permissions` need to have the `Get` ticked. And the `Key Permissions`, despite the fact that you may not have any keys at all in this vault, need to have `Get` and `Sign`. You would have thought these two would be in the certificate perms...
4. Go back to the application you just created. Select the `Certificates & secrets`, and either choose to upload a certificate (a new one purely for accessing the Key Vault remotely) or create a `client secret`. If the latter, keep a copy of the password, you won't see it again!
5. In the `Overview` section of the app will be the `Application (client) ID`. This, and the password or certificate, is what will be fed to the Azure Sign Tool later on in a Pipelines task.

Handling the actual code signing from Azure requires a number of steps. The following applies to Microsoft hosted agents, although similar issues will affect any private agents that you have.

1. The Azure Sign Tool needs the .NET Core SDK to be installed, but a version that's at least version 2.x, and since the **latest** .NET Core SDK is [always used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection), this means as long as the version of Windows is current enough, you don't need to install it yourself. And you can see which version of the [SDK is shipped with which Windows agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent).

   The current `Hosted` OS version in Azure Pipelines, also called `Default Hosted`, is, at the time of writing, Windows Server 2012 R2. Which isn't up to date enough. Installing a newer .NET Core SDK to overcome this is a time drag on every build, and although the installation works, calling the Azure Sign Tool may not work. It seems to be finding only older versions of the SDK, and throws this error: `Unable to find an entry point named 'SignerSignEx3' in DLL 'mssign32'.`

   So the easiest thing to do is change your build to use a later OS image. Windows 2019 works like a charm. And there is no need to install any version of .NET Core.
2. Then create a command line task to install the Azure Sign Tool. You can use a .NET Core CLI task as well, but there is no need. In the task, type this:

   ```
   set DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true
   dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool --version 2.0.17
   ```

   Naturally using whichever version that you want.

   The DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE environment variable isn't strictly necessary, but setting it speeds things up quite a bit ([see here for an explanation](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Stop-wasting-time-during-NET-Core-builds)).
3. Finally, create another command line task and type in the Azure Sign Tool command that you wish to run with. On Windows this would be something like below, note with `^` not `/` as a line continuation marker. Naturally, see [here for more parameter information](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool):

   ```
    AzureSignTool.exe sign -du "MY-URL" ^
      -kvu https://MY-VAULT-NAME.vault.azure.net ^
      -kvi CLIENT-ID-BIG-GUID ^
      -kvs CLIENT-PASSWORD ^
      -kvc MY-CERTIFICATE-NAME ^
      -tr http://timestamp.digicert.com ^
      -v ^
      $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Path/To/My/Setup/Exe
   ```

And in theory, you should have success! The output of the sign tool is rather good, and usually nails where the problem is.

## Re-issuing Certificates

If you need to re-issue a certificate, the situation is quite different.

1. In Azure, go to the certificate and click on it, opening a page showing the versions of that certificate, both current and older versions.
2. Click the 'New Version' button, probably accepting the defaults (depending on the choices you wish to make) and click 'Create'.
3. This takes you back to the Versions page, and there will be a message box stating 'The creation of certificate XXXX is currently pending'. Click there (or on the 'Certificate Operation' button) to open the 'Certificate Operation' side page. Once there, download the CSR (certificate signing request).
4. In GlobalSign, follow their instructions to [re-issue](https://support.globalsign.com/digital-certificates/digital-certificates-life-cycle/reissue-certificate-client-digital-certificates) the existing certificate. Once it has been re-issued, they will send an email describing how to download it.
5. Log into GlobalSign again, and after entering the temporary password, open the CSR and copy the whole text (which starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`) into GlobalSign. Submit it.
6. Download using the 'Install My Certificate' button. Then in the Azure 'Certificate Operation' side page - use the 'Merge Signed Request' button that to upload the .CER file to Azure. This creates the new version of the certificate.
7. Disable the old version of the certificate.

Comment: Thanks Paul - you've saved me the trouble of writing it up :)

Comment: I have followed these steps and I'm getting error "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden" on AzureSignTool step in my pipeline. I have granted permissions in key vault's Access Policies to my 'App Registration' application, Azure DevOps Service Principal, and even to Azure DevOps role. What am I missing?

note: according to pipeline output, it is successfully acquiring token certificate and secret.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the whole account, sorry. I'd suggest contacting Azure support, they were very useful in the past.

Comment: @Anodyne - Did you issue your CSR from within the Azure KeyVault?

Comment: I needed "--ignore-failed-sources" on the "dotnet tool install" bit to allow it to skip over the azure devops artifacts repository we use locally and check nuget.org next.  and "CLIENT-PASSWORD" was the "value" when creating the secret. Otherwise these instructions were fantastic and saved me loads of time!

Comment: How would this work in an On-Premise Azure DevOps environment?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this guide also https://seankilleen.com/2020/05/how-to-use-azuresigntool-to-sign-files-with-azure-devops-using-a-certificate-in-azure-keyvault/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's able to do this in Azure DevOps Service Build pipeline.

For normal situation,  we usually use [SignTool.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) commands to sign files. There is also an extension [**Code Signing**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stefankert.codesigning) in marketplace,  which could sign a single file, you could use script to run SignTool.exe commands for multiple files.

So you can export your codesigning certificate to a pfx file, which you then upload as a secure file to Azure Devops secure file storage which makes it available to your builds.

Azure DevOps could store secure files. Check this link for details: [Secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)

[Azure Key Vaul](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates)t instance is kind of more complicated. We also have an Azure Key Vault task.

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to download secrets such
>   as authentication keys, storage account keys, data encryption keys,
>   .PFX files, and passwords from an Azure Key Vault instance.
>
> The task can be used to fetch the latest values of all or a subset of
>   secrets from the vault, and set them as variables that can be used in
>   subsequent tasks of a pipeline.

Not sure how GlobalSign  will integrate code sign with your environment. Theoretically, it's able to do this. For the detail parts and implementation, you may need to discuss with their pre-sales. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I think the main issue here is that GlobalSign won't let us have the private key for the code signing certificate (for security reasons). They insist on the key being held on a USB token, HSM or in Azure Key Vault. This means we can't export the private key to a PFX file.I have, however, found [AzureSignTool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool) which looks like it might do the job. If that works for us, I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: I've actually just got the certificate into Key Vault about half an hour ago, so I'll update when/if I get signing working.

Comment: @Anodyne I know this is old but did you ever get your exported token working in Key Vault?

Comment: @phanf See the answer above by Paul F. Wood. I was not able to export the key from the USB token (that isn’t possible, by design) but I was able to have GlobalSign issue a new certificate that is now held in Azure Key Vault and use AzureSignTool.

Comment: The following information might also be useful: I have more recently started work on a new project that is packaged as a VSTO add-in, and AzureSignTool isn’t able to sign the ClickOnce manifests that are required for VSTO. For that project, I eventually settled on https://signpath.io which can sign every type of file I can think of.

Comment: @Anodyne We have tried to build our ClickOnce project with signpath.io, so far have been unsuccessful sending them the correct .zip artifact and manifest etc. Would you have information on how you add signpath.io into an Azure pipeline? Thanks.

Comment: @phanf It was pretty straightforward using the SignPath pipeline task extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SignPath.signpath-tasks

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking for this and using RBAC, I found these steps essential:

1. Key Vault Reader on the RESOURCE GROUP
2. Key Vault Certificates Officer on the KEY VAULT and on the CERTIFICATE
3. Key Vault Crypto Office on the CERTIFICATE (to use the key for signing!)

Comment: 2 years later I used only "Key Vault Reader" and "Key Vault Crypto User" roles assigned to my app principal name in the vault's IAM. Nothing else needed by AzureSignTool itself. I used other roles for managing the vault, but not for signing.