# Which platform for an HSM enabled EV certificate

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I'm currently in the process of purchasing an EV certificate that I plan on using to sign the build output from an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Based on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475144/how-to-sign-code-built-using-azure-pipelines-using-a-certificate-key-in-azure-ke/57934787#57934787) I understand that I need to make sure that I purchase an HSM enabled certificate. When selecting HSM, the provider of choice is asking which **platform** the cert is going to be used on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I could not find out which one Azure DevOps is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than Azure DevOps, as you'll be keeping the certificate in Azure Key Vault, that is where the HSM configuration is done. Azure Key Vault has a number of FIPS 140-2 Level 2 compliant HSMs available, you can find them documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/keys/hsm-protected-keys).

Both nShield and Luna are supported HSMs on Azure Key Vault which I can see listed in the list you have posted.

nCipher who are the vendor for nSheild HSMs supports both [nCipher BYOK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/keys/hsm-protected-keys-ncipher) and [native BYOK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/keys/hsm-protected-keys-byok).